# Conversion of custom init routines in Swift

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, initialization, swift, uinavigationitem

I need to subclass SVModalWebViewController.m ([GitHub](https://github.com/samvermette/SVWebViewController)), which is itself a subclass of `UINavigationController`, and am incorporating this code into a new app that will be created entirely in Swift.  I've run into several issues, so I decided to first convert just this very simple class into Swift to debug.

Initialization is a little different in Swift compared with Objective-C ([read more about Swift initialization here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/Initialization.html)), which is why I'm not returning `self` in the Swift code.

Here's the original Obj-C code (minus the *.h, which instantiates `barsTintColor`):

```
#import "SVModalWebViewController.h"
#import "SVWebViewController.h"

@interface SVModalWebViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) SVWebViewController *webViewController;

@end


@implementation SVModalWebViewController

#pragma mark - Initialization


- (id)initWithAddress:(NSString*)urlString {
    return [self initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
}

- (id)initWithURL:(NSURL *)URL {
    self.webViewController = [[SVWebViewController alloc] initWithURL:URL];
    if (self = [super initWithRootViewController:self.webViewController]) {
        UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone
                                                                                    target:self.webViewController
                                                                                    action:@selector(doneButtonClicked:)];

        if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
            self.webViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = doneButton;
        else
            self.webViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = doneButton;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:NO];

    self.webViewController.title = self.title;
    self.navigationBar.tintColor = self.barsTintColor;
}

@end
```

And here's the entire Swift version of the class (I simplified to just one init method since I didn't need to init with URL specifically):

```
import UIKit

class SVModalWebViewController: UINavigationController {
    var webViewController: SVWebViewController!
    var barsTintColor: UIColor?

    // This was added because of a compiler error indicating it needed to be added
    init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String!, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle!) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    }

    init(address urlString: String!) {
        let url: NSURL = NSURL.URLWithString(urlString)
        self.webViewController = SVWebViewController(URL: url)
        super.init(rootViewController: self.webViewController)

        let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Done, target: self.webViewController, action: Selector("doneButtonClicked:"))

        if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad {
            self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = doneButton
        } else {
            self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = doneButton
        }
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        // self.title may not be set, and is considered an optional in Swift, so we have to check first
        if self.title {self.webViewController.title = self.title}
        self.navigationBar.tintColor = self.barsTintColor
    }
}
```

The issue I'm having relates to setting the `Done` button in the `navigationItem`.  Currently they're not showing up at all when this code is called:

```
let webViewController = SVModalWebViewController(address: "http://www.google.com");
webViewController.barsTintColor = UIColor.blueColor()
self.presentModalViewController(webViewController, animated: true)
```

The modal view appears just fine and I'm able to correctly set the bar color property, but the `Done` button does not show up.  It appears that I don't have proper access to the `navigationItem` of the `UINavigationController`.  Note that I had to add the init with nibName method due to a compiler error without it.  This wasn't required in the Obj-C code and I'll admit I'm not sure why it's needed in Swift - that could be part of the issue.

Any thoughts as to why I cannot set the `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem` property of the `UINavigationController`?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A UINavigationController does not have a `navigationItem`. Well, it does, but it's useless. It is the `navigationItem` of the child controller (in this case, the `rootViewController`, which you are also calling `self.webViewController`) that appears in the navigation bar.

Comment: You're right.  I had 'self.webViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = doneButton' initially but took out 'webViewController' when debugging.  When I add 'webViewController' I get the 'can't unwrap Optionals.None' error.  Given that I didn't instantiate the navigationItem and am, in fact, setting it here (I already know it's nil), how do I fix this error?

Comment: Yes, I've translated a _lot_ of code from Objective-C to Swift and I find it is very, very easy to make a typo like this.

Comment: That is presumably because you have no `webViewController`. But really, that would be a different question. I answered (correctly, I believe) the question you did ask.

Comment: Thanks.  But shouldn't I have one by that point?  I call `var webViewController: SVWebViewController!` at the top of the class and instantiate it with `self.webViewController = SVWebViewController(URL: url)` in the init, prior to the code in question.

Comment: And evidently that initializer is returning nil. I don't know anything about SVWebViewController so I don't know (or care) why that is.